# Can I resize a GADBannerView?

Tags: ios, admob

I'm using a custom `GADBannerView` in my application. Currently I'm getting the following frame.

```
<GADBannerView: 0x7fd146f9d8a0; frame = (0 0; 640 260); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd1455a2880>>
```

Can I resize the `frame` to 320x130? If I resize it I get a "No ads to display" error. If I keep it the original size I receive ads.

Is there is any way to change the size of `GADBannerView`?

Comment: yes you can...using baannerview.frame =cgrectmake(20 ,20,1024,90);

Comment: I can resize which you given size but I need 320x130 size. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

**No.** we can't resize the `GADBannerView` We can show the Ad which they given sizes. If we want to customize the `GADBannerView` size give the Ad size in backend.